# ASP.NET Gridview Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a Gridview with 3 columns (CompanyName, Volume, counter) I would like to have the counter column be all buttons and when a user clicks the button it increments the counter by 1.  I'm not sure how to properly setup the update command.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
                SortExpression="CompanyName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Volume" HeaderText="Volume" 
                SortExpression="Volume" />
            <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="counter" HeaderText="counter" 
            ButtonType="button"/>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LiquorStoreConnectionString1 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LiquorStoreConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName], [Volume], [counter] FROM [Company]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

All I need it to do is increment by 1 every time the button is pressed on that specific row.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John! I apologize for doing that and I will read your link that you've provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
... UpdateCommand="Update COMPANY SET counter=@Counter +1 WHERE CopmanyName=@Company"
<columns> 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="counter" DataField="Counter" />             
</columns>
```

Make sure you have the bound field names correct.
I haven't tested to see if this + 1 works with a bound field. If it does not, then we'll have to use OnRowCommand to update the database manually, then you can re-bind the view and see updated counter. More importantly, I don't see a nice primary key for your Company so you can do the update... So my sample is using the CompanyName, and that is danger danger.

Comment: Hi bugnuker!

I just created a primary key called Id with the updatecommand `UpdateCommand="Update COMPANY SET counter=@Counter +1 WHERE Id=@Id"`

this just increments each column row by one.  I want all counter rows to be zero unless someone clicks on one then that specific row becomes 1.  If that makes sense?

Comment: I think you might need to do the OnRowCommand.
Click on your gridview in design mode, then on the properties of the gridview, you will have a "lightning" bolt icon. Click this. You should then see "OnRowCommand" if you double click this, it will auto create the event for you in code. Now you just need to write a SQL update command. You will have the RowID (if it has been bound correctly) in the arguments (e) for your "where" clause.

Comment: I don't have "OnRowCommand" I do have "RowCommand" however and when I double click on it it gives me `protected void GridViewCommandEventHandler(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){}`

Comment: That is what you want. e will have some row properties. Like e["COLUMNNAME"] and stuff. You can run update command manually here.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to update the database?
You can catch the button click event in gridview row command .
Take a look at link given below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx

Comment: Hi Karthi,

Yes I would like it to update the database after every click if that's possible.

Comment: were you able to get the rowcommand working?? just create a stored procedure that increments the value and call it in row command